# Datalab: moving notebook to other folder

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I made a copy of a notebook in datalab. But instead of having the copy in the same folder - it was created at the root folder. That is probably a bug that needs to get fixed. In the mean time I tried to move the file to the right folder but the datalab UI doesn't seem to support that.

How do I move datalab notebook to the other folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebooks created under the /datalab path are meant for official samples, tutorials, etc. While you could create new notebooks there, making a copy of a notebook will instead create it in the root. If you are experiencing this elsewhere though that sounds like a bug.

There is no direct facility for moving notebooks; however you can download a notebook as a .ipynb file and then from the main tree view you can navigate to the directory you want it to go in and click on 'Upload' to upload it.

Comment: I see, so it is download, upload, delete old. Not the most intuitive but works.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to move a notebook into a folder that is not part of the official samples, then you may consider the following method:

**Move notebooks using the rename function:** 

One method to move a notebook is to rename the notebook and include the relative path to the destination folder before the filename.

For example, assume that we have the following in the root folder

- A notebook called `Notebook2.ipynb`
- A folder called `MyNotebooks`

── MyNotebooks 
│         └── Notebook1.ipynb
│
Notebook2.ipynb

To move  `Notebook2.ipynb` into `MyNotebooks`, click on the notebook, then click rename, then rename the notebook as `MyNotebooks/Notebook2.ipynb`

Now you should see,
── MyNotebooks 
│         └── Notebook1.ipynb
│         └── Notebook2.ipynb

**Note**: You will not be able to rename a notebook while there is an active session for the notebook. Make sure to stop the session first by clicking on `Sessions`, then clicking `Shutdown` on the specific notebook you want to move.

Comment: This no longer works:

"Invalid notebook name. Notebook names must have 1 or more characters and can contain any characters except :/\. Please enter a new notebook name:"

Answer (score 3):

I would rather recommend that you connect to the DataLab instance via ssh and move the file.

`default path: /mnt/disks/datalab-pd/content/datalab/`